# Specify config file for @SpringApplicationConfiguration

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, integration-testing

Currently my integration test look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = PingFacadeApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class PingResourceTest {
    // some tests that use RestTemplate to contact PingFacadeApplication
}
```

`PingFacadeApplication` is defined like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "edu.self.myapp.ping")
public class PingFacadeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "ping-facade-server");
        SpringApplication.run(PingFacadeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When normally starting (i.e. running the jar) `PingFacadeApplication`, the config file (`ping-facade-server.yml`) is correctly read from `src/main/resources`. However, when running my integration tests, the config files appears to never be read because the server is always started on port 8080. I've also tried to put the config file in `src/test/resources` but no luck.

I know I can change the port in the `WebIntegrationTest` annotation but I'd like to avoid having it in two places.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you sure the file is not read, could it be just that System.setproperty has no effect there?

Comment: The `main` method is only called when you run your application normally, it isn't called when you're running a test so the system property won't be getting set.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Indeed, the class must be started another way internally... I've found a way around it though, will post it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to indicate the name of the configuration file with the `@WebIntegrationTest` annotation:

```
// ...
@WebIntegrationTest("spring.config.name=ping-facade-server")
public class PingResourceTest {
```

In my case I have a ping-facade-server.yml file in src/test/resources.